# XML to string using RSACryptoServiceProvider methods

Tags: c#, rsa

I have a problem with getting my string from xml. In xml I have my public key generated by `RSACryptoServiceProvider`

So this is a code that I'm generating RSA and I save it to a file:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(LENGHT_OF_KEY);
var public_key = rsa.ToXmlString(false); // RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(public_keys_path + name, true))
        {
            sw.Write(public_key);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
```

And then I try to get a key from a file and then convert it to a string:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(public_keys_path.ToString() + user))
{
      String public_keyXML = sr.ReadToEnd();
      String public_key = rsa.FromXmlString(public_keyXML); // here i get the error
}
```

I get the error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'."

Even though the method `FromXmlString` returns a string! It doesn't make sense for me. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring(v=vs.100).aspx), `FromXmlString`does *not* return a `string`.  It returns `void`.  It is used to "Initialize an RSA object from the key information from an XML string."

Comment: Ok, @Tim is right. The truth is that FromXmlString returns void. My fault. My apologies.